SVG is different only on Iphones but working fine on rest of the devices



Android
iPhone









Why is the toggle SVG reacting that way on iPhones, whereas it is working fine on Android devices, PC, laptops, etc?
Where could be the issue be?
SVG code:
<label className="themeToggle st-sunMoonThemeToggleBtn" type="checkbox">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    id="themeToggle"
    className="themeToggleInput"
    checked={theme === "light"}
    onChange={toggleTheme}
  />
  <svg
    width="18"
    height="18"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    fill={theme === "dark" ? "currentColor" : "currentColor"}
    stroke="none"
    className={`relative top-1 -ml-3 lg:ml-12 md:top-1.5 ${
      theme === "dark" ? "text-gray-300" : "text-gray-700"
    }`}
  >
    <mask id="moon-mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" fill="white"></rect>
      <circle cx="11" cy="3" r="8" fill="black"></circle>
    </mask>
    <circle
      className="sunMoon"
      cx="10"
      cy="10"
      r="7"
      mask="url(#moon-mask)"
    ></circle>
    <g>
      <circle className="sunRay sunRay1" cx="18" cy="10" r="1.5"></circle>
      <circle className="sunRay sunRay2" cx="14" cy="16.928" r="1.5"></circle>
      <circle className="sunRay sunRay3" cx="6" cy="16.928" r="1.5"></circle>
      <circle className="sunRay sunRay4" cx="2" cy="10" r="1.5"></circle>
      <circle className="sunRay sunRay5" cx="6" cy="3.1718" r="1.5"></circle>
      <circle className="sunRay sunRay6" cx="14" cy="3.1718" r="1.5"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
</label>;


The meta viewport is:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

I don't think there is much to try since the size is nearly the same for all mobile phones.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

The code you have given so far creates the same shapes and relative sizes on Windows11 Edge and iPhone 17 Safari so I don't think we can help until we have a runnable snippet that definitely shows the problem.

@AHaworth You can see the code over here. It exactly the same.
https://uiverse.io/Type-Delta/happy-mule-45

Please read the helpful comments given by @Paulie_D

@AHaworth I tried pasting the code, but it isnt letting me post by saying the post is mostly code and there isnt enough details...

The only thing that I notice on https://book-ai-phi.vercel.app/ is that, when resizing the window from the width 775px to 640px (probably depends on font size) the icon will get squeezed and get smaller and smaller until the burger menu kicks in (less than 640px). Maybe if you can fix that, it also helps on the icin being small on the iPhone.

@TalhaAbdurRaheem you need to cut it down to a [mcve] i.e. just include the parts that exhibit the problem and not your whole site/page.

You have to apply the width:100%;  to the SVG by using following steps,

First of all encapsulate the SVG in the <span> tag.
Paste your SVG in the  tag and apply CSS as below,



.themeToggle span{
  display: inline-block;
  width:70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.themeToggle span svg{
  position:absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width:100%;
}



It will help you to retain the height and with same in all screen size.
